# max items in array multi-select laravel blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, multi-select

So suppose in my blade template I have 1000+ items in a multi-select like so:

```
< select multiple='multiple' > 

@foreach($manyItems as $item) 

< option value= $item > $item </ option > 

@endforeach 

</ select >
```

where in this example, suppose $manyItems has 2000+ items. Now, suppose the inputs for this blade template are collected and processed in a laravel controller. When I try to select all of the items, and some more, for some reason it only selects the first 1000 items, and it can't hold any more data (it drops the other 1000+ items, and the other fields I selected). So it seems like the laravel blade template can only pass in 1000 items in Request::all(). Is this true? (or am I derping around?) welp me. weird bug alert.

Also I disabled all of my javascript to verify that it's not javascript/jquery causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Laravel issue, it is PHP engine related.

PHP 5.3.9 introduced the [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) config option, which is defaulted to a value of 1000.

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.

You can change the value by updating the server's php.ini or by adding it in an .htaccess file.

Comment: How do I edit the .htaccess file or php.ini file in laravel for this?
I first changed /etc/php5/cli/php.ini but that didn't result in the changes in laravel. Next I also tried to add this line in my public/.htaccess file:      php_value max_input_vars 1000 but no changes occurred as well

Comment: @mark4284 You have to change the apache php.ini not the cli. To check which ini file is loaded use phpinfo. Also do not forget to restart apache after that.

Comment: Also I got "etc/php5/fpm/php.ini" as the Loaded Configuration File. I changed the max_input_vars to 4000 and from here, the max_input_vars hasn't changed still.

Comment: Alright, I got it to work now (idk why it wasn't working earlier, i did edit and restarted -.-) anyhow, thanks!